# How to interpret documentation

Tags: c, file

can someone please explain how to interpret what this actually means? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_file_io.htm

Specifically for example:

```
int fscanf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...)
```

I kind of just guessed, but is this right? `fscanf` returns an integer indicating how many values were correctly scanned in? Also, how come I can just use `fscanf(fp, %d)` etc.? How do I know that this is what is the syntax? I am trying to understand this documentation so that I can understand other function documentations too. Alot of times I am confused. Can someone please take time to explain? For example, if i did `FILE *  = fp`, i know i can just use `fscanf(fp, etc...)` but I dont know why that is. Thanks alot!!!

Comment: oh... so think of these declarations as actual function declarations? that makes a lot of sense now that I think of it. So all these functions like printf are predefined right? It all makes sense now.. how do I know what File* stream is? Does that mean that that function takes an argument of type FILE* in that part of the syntax?

Comment: Those functions are actually defined in header files (maybe automatically) included in your code!  You can find them on the file system, the decls are literally cut/pasted right from them into the man pages.  the one for fprintf on my system is located at /usr/include/stdio.h...

Comment: Unfortunately there is no separate way to look up C /types/, so you have to look at the functions that use them and hope that explains it!   But yes, the first argument to fscanf if a FILE* (that is, a pointer to a FILE structure, also defined in the headers)

Answer (score 1):

The line you quoted is a C declaration - it has a different syntax than a function call.  In particular, each argument as well as the function itself is preceded by a type.  The function "prototype" there is just the same syntax as you would use a forward decl in an actual C program.

Then, you have the extra complication of varargs (that '...' bit), which means that any number (zero or more) of any type args can come after the 'format'.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you see [scanf's declaration](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/?kw=scanf)  `int scanf ( const char * format, ... )`, you will find it's similar with `fscanf` except that `fscanf` has a extra parameter `FILE *stream`. In fact, you can treat scanf as a special `fscanf` with its extra parameter as `stdin`, that is `scanf ( const char * format, ... )` is equivament of `fscanf(stdin, const char * format, ...)`. So how you use `scanf`, you can use `fscanf` as the same way.